# Is there a way to execute django tags sent from external javascript file after page has loaded

Tags: jquery, arrays, django

I have a page where I use autocomplete to get hotels from database then try updating the hotel found into the django app but I face a problem since I am tring to execute the raw django tags from javascript after the page has loaded which is triggered by the jquery select 
the code I am working with now is here

```
function updateContent(id, place){

var html_cont = '<div class="hotel{{place.id}} panel lastminute4"'+
         ' style="margin:10px; padding:10px; text-align:left; padding-bottom:0px;">'+
        ' {% with '+ id +'|get_hotel as sel_hotel %}'+
        ' <h5 style="font-weight:900; text-transform:uppercase;">{{sel_hotel.hotel_name}}</h5>'+
        ' {% with 4|get_rooms as hotel_rooms%}'+
        ' {% for room in hotel_rooms %}'+
        ' <h6>{{room.title}}  *ksh. <span style="color:green;">{{room.amount}}</span></h6>'+
        ' <button class="btn btn-default btn_minus" data-target="htl_{{place.id}}_{{room.id}}"'+
                'style="display:inline;" formtarget="cost_{{place.id}}_{{room.id}}">&minus; room</button>'+
        ' <input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" value="0" formtarget="{{room.amount}}"'+
               ' id="htl_{{place.id}}_{{room.id}}" readonly style="width:60px; background:white; display:inline;">'+
        '<button class="btn btn-default btn_add" data-target="htl_{{place.id}}_{{room.id}}"'+
                ' style="display:inline;" formtarget="cost_{{place.id}}_{{room.id}}">&plus; room</button>'+
         '<b id="cost_{{place.id}}_{{room.id}}" style="font-size:15px;"> = Ksh.0</b>'+
        '{% endfor %}'+
        '{% endwith %}'+
        '{% endwith %}'+
    '</div>';
    div_id = "#append_hotel"+ place;
    $(div_id).append(html_cont);
}
```

I expect to get executed tags rendered to the template and not the raw django tags with curly brackets and the % sign

Comment: No, of course that is not possible.

Comment: okey thanks.. then how can I ever do this? am really stack

Comment: You probably want to use Ajax to return a rendered template fragment

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Daniel Roseman for the ajax idea I managed to do that by calling an ajax function to fetch some htmnl template that is updated with the content and append it to the region I wanted
I made a django view like this

```py
def get_hotel(request,id, pk):
    place = Location.objects.get(id=id)
    hotel = Hotels.objects.get(id=id)

    context = {
        'rooms':hotel.rooms.all(),
        'hotel':hotel,
        'place':place,
    }
    html = render_to_string("home/hotel_rooms.html", context)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

This was the view to update content to a template **home/hotel_rooms.html** I then made the template live this

```
<div class="hotel{{place.id}} panel lastminute4"
     style="margin:10px; padding:10px; text-align:left; padding-bottom:0px;">
    <h5><a style="font-weight:900; text-transform:uppercase;" href="" data-toogle="tooltip">{{hotel.hotel_name}}</a>
    {% for room in rooms %}
    <h6>{{room.title}} *ksh. <span style="color:green;">{{room.amount}}</span></h6>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn_minus" data-target="htl_{{place.id}}_{{room.id}}"
            style="display:inline;" formtarget="cost_{{place.id}}_{{room.id}}">&minus; room
    </button>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" value="0" formtarget="{{room.amount}}"
           id="htl_{{place.id}}_{{room.id}}" readonly style="width:60px; background:white; display:inline;">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn_add" data-target="htl_{{place.id}}_{{room.id}}"
            style="display:inline;" formtarget="cost_{{place.id}}_{{room.id}}">&plus; room
    </button>
    <b id="cost_{{place.id}}_{{room.id}}" style="font-size:15px;"> = Ksh.0</b>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

and then in  my ajax

```
function updateContent(id, pk){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/get_hotel/' + id +'/'+ pk,
        data: id,
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(data){
             div_id = "#append_hotel"+ pk;
             $(div_id).append(data);
        },//success
        error: function(){
            console.logs("AJAX - failure.");
        }//error
    });

};
```

thank you so much this work like a charm